# DBfit server on local machine problems with fixtures and constructors

Tags: java, database, dbfit

1. I installed DBfit as specified here: http://dbfit.github.io/dbfit/docs/getting-started.html
2. Configured the test and the database;
3. Ran the startFitnesse.bat;
4. Defined a test;

But when the I run the test the output is this: 
[image]

Including the suggested variable: !define TEST_SYSTEM {slim} gives me this:
[image]

**IF I DELETE THE !path lib/*.jar - IT STILL GIVES ME THE SAME.**

I realize that DBfit can't find the .CLASS files - just don't know how to solve it. 
Is the path variable incorrect?

Any suggestions on what to do will be rewarded.

P.S. my test script:

```
!define TEST_SYSTEM {slim}

!path lib/*.jar 

!|dbfit.SQLServerTest|
!|Connect|localhost:2256|mindaugasb|MyPassword|TEST1_DB|

!|query|select * from dbo.Employees|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with !|dbfit.SQLServerTest| parameter. I have copied it from somewhere incorreclty !|dbfit.SqlServerTest|.

If anyone reads in this with similar issues here is a helpful forum where the issue was solved, and the responses where very prompt: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dbfit/4mrHAHvW4M0